# Android with webview with remote website

Tags: android, webview

My android app has a webview which directly goes to the remote PHP site and shows user the registration form.

My question is, once user get registered successfully I want to close the webview and start another activity which is in native view. But how can I know whether he/she got registered successfully or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

In your PHP code, when the user gets registered successfully, redirect user to a unique link(this link will be used in your android code). Let's assume the link you redirect user to is "https://blablabla.com/successfully_registered"

In the WebViewClient's OnPageStarted method used by your WebView, Get the URL and check if it's similar to your redirect URL we assumed you used in your PHP code.

For Example:

```
WebView wv = findViewById(R.id.webview);
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){

            //check if URL is similar to redirect URL
             if(url.contains("https://blablabla.com/successfully_registered")){
                view.stopLoading();
                //user have been successfully registered. Start another activity or do something else...
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help!